# How does this regex work when finding the last occurrence of a word?

Tags: regex

I came across a regex like the following:

```
foo(?!.*foo)
```

if it is fed with `foo bar bar foo`, it will find the last occurrence of foo. I know it uses a mechanism called negative lookahead which means it will match a word which not end with characters after the ?!. But how does the regex here works?

Comment: You could make this a bit more dynamic by using groups `(foo)(?!.*\1)` or recursion if your engine supports it `(foo)(?!.*(?1))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It matches `foo` only if it is *not* followed (`?!`) by any more text (`.*`) containing `foo` in it.

Answer (score 9):

Slightly different answer from sshashank (because the word `containing` in his answer doesn't work for me and in regex you *have to* be pedantic—it's all about precision.) I'm 100% sure sshashank knows this and only phrased it that way for brevity.

The regex matches `foo`, not followed (i.e., negative lookahead `(?!`) by this:

{{{any number of any characters (i.e., `.*`) *then* the characters `foo`}}}

If the lookahead fails, the portion corresponding to `.*` does not *contain* `foo`. `foo` comes later.

See this [automatic translation](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=foo%28?!.%2afoo%29):

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  foo                      'foo'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    foo                      'foo'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

The same in different words from regex101:

> /foo(?!.*foo)/
>
> ```
> foo matches the characters foo literally (case sensitive)
> (?!.*foo) Negative Lookahead - Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below
>     .* matches any character (except newline)
>         Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
>     foo matches the characters foo literally (case sensitive)
> ```

What does RegexBuddy have to say?

### foo(?!.*foo)

```
foo(?!.*foo)
```

- Match the character string “foo” literally (case sensitive) `foo`
- Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead) `(?!.*foo)`

  - Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed, carriage return, next line, line separator, paragraph separator) `.*`

    - Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `*`
  - Match the character string “foo” literally (case sensitive) `foo`

Answer (score 4):

**Negative lookahead** is essential if you want to match something not followed by something else.

Short explanation:

```
foo(?!.*foo) matches foo when not followed by any character except \n and `foo`
```

For example, say you have the following two strings.

```
foobar
barfoo
```

And the regular expression:

```
foo(?!bar)
```

This matches `foo` when not followed by **bar** so it would match the string `barfoo` here.